# Linux shows I have write permission but I can't remove this file

Tags: linux, permissions

Linux shows I have write permission but I can't remove this file. I've already checked and I have execute permission on every parent directory. Any idea how this could be happening?:

```
deployer@my-web:/usr/local/bin$ ls -la
total 10656
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root        4096 Feb 11 21:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root     root        4096 Feb  3 13:21 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 deployer deployer 1836198 Mar 18 19:05 composer

deployer@my-web:/usr/local/bin$ rm composer
rm: cannot remove ‘composer’: Permission denied
```

Comment: Removing a file is modifying the containing directory, not the file itself.  You do not have `w` permission on `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you need not only permissions on the file but permissions on the directory holding the file.  In classical UNIX a directory is really a special kind of file - one that holds pointers to the files inside it.  So that's why you need write (w) access on the directory.

In this case, you would need to change (or have a privileged owner change) the permissions on /usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions for directories aren't exactly the same as they are for files.
Write permission allows the user to create, delete, or modify any files or subdirectories, even if the file or subdirectory is owned by another user.

In the case of a directory, nothing much changes as the same command is used. However, because directories usually contain files that also need to be assigned to the new user or group, we use the '**-R**' flag, which stands for '**recursive**' - in other words all subdirectories and their files:

```
chown -R user:group dirname
```